# Virtual Hosts for HTTPS on Mac Apache 2

Tags: macos, apache, apache2, virtualhost

I have a site for which I had set up a VHost. I need both HTTP and HTTPS. While the HTTP seems to be functioning well, whenever I access HTTPS functions, I get "Safari Can't Open The Server" message. I suspect that the issue is with the http_vhosts.conf file. Below are the entries for the site in question. What can be going wrong?

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/xxx/www/sites/xxxxxx"
    ServerName http://xxxxxx.dev
    ServerAlias xxxxxx.dev
    UseCanonicalName on
    <Directory "/Users/xxx/www/sites/xxxxxx">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
  </Virtualhost>

  <Virtualhost *:443>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/xxx/www/sites/xxxxxx"
    ServerName https://xxxxxx.dev
    ServerAlias https://xxxxxx.dev
    UseCanonicalName off
    <Directory "/Users/xxx/www/sites/xxxxxx">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
  </Virtualhost>
```

Comment: You need to turn on SSLEngine and also provide a public certificate and private key to use https.

Comment: Do I need the certificates even for local development?

Comment: Yes if you want to use https. Otherwise how would the browser know if it's local or not? You can generate your own self signed certs and install them on your browser to avoid purchasing real ones, or just ignore the errors due to self signed certs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a certificate:

```
  <Virtualhost *:443>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/xxx/www/sites/xxxxxx"
    ServerName https://xxxxxx.dev
    ServerAlias https://xxxxxx.dev
    UseCanonicalName off
    <Directory "/Users/xxx/www/sites/xxxxxx">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

  </Virtualhost>
```

To create your self signed certificate you can use the command :

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
```

By the way if your SeverAlias is the same as your ServerName, you can remove the ServerAlias, it is not requiered